# How to save pandas dataframe from praw to xlsx?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter, praw

I'm trying to save a dataframe to xlsx in Colab. I get the data with praw:

```
sm = reddit.submission(url="https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1irtkq/taxi_drivers_whats_the_deepest_secret_youve/")
sm.comments.replace_more(limit=0)

data = []

for top_level_comment in sm.comments.list():
  data.append([top_level_comment.body,
               top_level_comment.author,
               top_level_comment.score,
               top_level_comment.created_utc,
               top_level_comment.depth,
               top_level_comment.id,
               top_level_comment.parent_id])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['body', 'author', 'score', 'created_utc', 'depth', 'id', 'parent_id'])
df
```

[image]

Everything looks fine, I got all the data. But when I save it I get an error in the praw library:

```
directory = '/content/downloads'
file_path = posixpath.join(directory, 'reddit.xlsx')
if not os.path.exists(directory):
  os.makedirs(directory)

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:  
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
  worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
  writer.save()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFound                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b8157734da77> in <module>()
      5 
      6 with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
----> 7   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
      8   worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)
   2254             startcol=startcol,
   2255             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
-> 2256             engine=engine,
   2257         )
   2258 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine)
    737             startrow=startrow,
    738             startcol=startcol,
--> 739             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
    740         )
    741         if need_save:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
    212             wks.freeze_panes(*(freeze_panes))
    213 
--> 214         for cell in cells:
    215             val, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)
    216 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in get_formatted_cells(self)
    685     def get_formatted_cells(self):
    686         for cell in itertools.chain(self._format_header(), self._format_body()):
--> 687             cell.val = self._format_value(cell.val)
    688             yield cell
    689 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in _format_value(self, val)
    433             elif self.float_format is not None:
    434                 val = float(self.float_format % val)
--> 435         if getattr(val, "tzinfo", None) is not None:
    436             raise ValueError(
    437                 "Excel does not support datetimes with "

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py in __getattr__(self, attribute)
     31         """Return the value of `attribute`."""
     32         if not attribute.startswith("_") and not self._fetched:
---> 33             self._fetch()
     34             return getattr(self, attribute)
     35         raise AttributeError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/models/reddit/redditor.py in _fetch(self)
    173 
    174     def _fetch(self):
--> 175         data = self._fetch_data()
    176         data = data["data"]
    177         other = type(self)(self._reddit, _data=data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/models/reddit/redditor.py in _fetch_data(self)
    170         name, fields, params = self._fetch_info()
    171         path = API_PATH[name].format(**fields)
--> 172         return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
    173 
    174     def _fetch(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py in request(self, method, path, params, data, files)
    630         """
    631         return self._core.request(
--> 632             method, path, data=data, files=files, params=params
    633         )
    634 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py in request(self, method, path, data, files, json, params)
    183         return self._request_with_retries(
    184             data=data, files=files, json=json, method=method,
--> 185             params=params, url=url)
    186 
    187 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/prawcore/sessions.py in _request_with_retries(self, data, files, json, method, params, url, retries)
    128                                   retries, saved_exception, url)
    129         elif response.status_code in self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS:
--> 130             raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
    131         elif response.status_code == codes['no_content']:
    132             return

NotFound: received 404 HTTP response
```

I'm confused: I already have the data. I don't need `http requests` any more.

I found that last pandas error is about `timezones`. What is happening?

```
raise ValueError(
                "Excel does not support datetimes with "
                "timezones. Please ensure that datetimes "
                "are timezone unaware before writing to Excel."
            )
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns in the dataframe?  Could perhaps one of the mistakenly be datetime?

Comment: Thanks. Author was a Reddit instance.

Answer (score 0):

As you allude to in your comment, the issue was that `top_level_comment.author` has type `Redditor`, which isn't supported by pandas and/or the Excel format.

To fix this, change `top_level_comment.author` to `str(top_level_comment.author)` (which will turn it into the string of the author's username).